# Counting occurrences based on condition in R (using dplyr ?)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataset similar to this
Year   ID   Type
2000   A      0
2001   A      0
2002   A      1
2000   B      0
2001   B      0
2002   C      1
2003   C      1

I want to summarize, probably with dplyr, so that I get the count of type zero and type 1 per year.

Example:
Year  Type   Count
2000    0     2
2000    1     0

Thanks a lot, and sorry for not creating the appropriate table for visualization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see where count is 0 then you need a final `complete` too.

```
df <- structure(
  list(Year = c(2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L,2003L),
       ID = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
       Type = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
       ), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA,-7L)
  )

df %>%
  group_by(Year, Type) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(Year, Type, fill = list(n = 0))
```

To return

```
   Year  Type     n
  <int> <int> <dbl>
1  2000     0     2
2  2000     1     0
3  2001     0     2
4  2001     1     0
5  2002     0     0
6  2002     1     2
7  2003     0     0
8  2003     1     1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want :

```
my_df <- my_df %>% group_by(Year, Type) %>% summarise(Count = n())
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted... thanks a lot mate!

Comment: Don't forget to checkmark the right answer mate !

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- structure(
  list(Year = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2000, 2001, 2002,2003),
       Id = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), 
       Type = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
  ), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(NA,-7L)
)
```

Maybe this could help:

```
table(df$Year, df$Type)

      0 1
  2000 2 0
  2001 2 0
  2002 0 2
  2003 0 1
```